# Recursive search with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working with the Google Drive API v2.

I trying to implement a search feature using the one included in the API.

It seems that the "children.list" is not recursive, meaning it doesn't look through all the subfolders. 
Do I have to implement it via multiple calls to the API, for each folder child reference? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, children.list nor files.list support recursive listing, so i think you will have to implement this as you mentioned.
Maybe this behavior is done by Google because the previous version of Drive (when it still was called Docs), allowed the files to be in more than one "label" (there were Labels, not Folders yet), remaining files holding that property may cause kind if an infinite loop

Comment: This answer suggests that the Docslist API and Drive API have different semantics. This is not the case. The Drive SDK also supports multiple parents and thus behaves like labels (except when it comes to deleting). Thus there are two solutions to the original question (1) do a recursive list, (2) have all descendants have the grandparent as a parent.

Comment: Where I find the problem that we can use a maximum of 20 parents in a query.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a list of ChildReferences, you cannot determine if they are a folder or not unless you actually retrieve the file. So if you are doing a large recursive search you should use batching to achieve this. I created a method to recursively change the owner of all the files in a folder, this might be of help:

```
private void updateFolderOwner(String folderId, final String newOwnerEmail) throws IOException{
    String permissionId = service.permissions().getIdForEmail(newOwnerEmail).execute().getId();

    Children.List request = service.children().list(folderId);

    JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Permission permission, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {}

        @Override
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    JsonBatchCallback<File> findFolderCallback = new JsonBatchCallback<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(File file, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
            if (file != null) {
                String fileExtension = file.getFileExtension();
                String mimeType = file.getMimeType();
                if (mimeType != null && mimeType.equals("application/vnd.google-apps.folder") && (fileExtension == null || fileExtension.equals(""))) {
                    //Recursively search this folder...
                    updateFolderOwner(file.getId(),newOwnerEmail);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    do {
        try {
            ChildList children = request.execute();

            BatchRequest changeOwnerBatch = service.batch();
            BatchRequest findFolderBatch = service.batch();

            Permission permission = new Permission();
            permission.setEmailAddress(newOwnerEmail);
            permission.setValue(newOwnerEmail);
            permission.setType("user");
            permission.setRole("owner");

            for (ChildReference child : children.getItems()) {
                service.files().get(child.getId()).queue(findFolderBatch, findFolderCallback);
                service.permissions().update(child.getId(), permissionId, permission).setTransferOwnership(true).queue(changeOwnerBatch, callback);
            }
            changeOwnerBatch.execute();
            findFolderBatch.execute();

            request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

}
```