# File/Folder search in the entire drive using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to search a filename/folder recursively in the entire google drive as Searcgh provided after logging in drive.google.com account. I found this thread [Recursive search with Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149200/recursive-search-with-google-drive-api) but looks like not an answer much easier. Still do we need to do recursively search all the folders and subfolder as mention in the thread. Or do we have an easier way in which it can be of the form of a simple query.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request is to search the entire corpus. You shouldn't need to do anything special.

You need to do a recursive search if you want to search under a subtree.

Comment: So in that case if there are some 50+ folders in my root, then I have to recursively search in all the deep rooted subfolders also. On the on other, I was on the impression that since searching a file in the My Drive(drive.google.com) levels does a recursive search. So was wandering if they provide that in the api also.